# Spring @Transactional read-only mode rollback behaviour

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, transactions

I have some service layer method with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` and this method causes some `RuntimeException` quite often (let's say it is some `NotFoundException` exception).

I'm using ORM Hibernate also for the DB interaction process.

Is it legal pattern to do so?

What is the default behaviour in this case in sense of "roll-back" behaviour?  Can it influence somehow badly on connections's state or lead to any problems?

---

It isn't something like "why not try it by your self?". I have a suspicion that this *could* lead to the `Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only` error in the same method after some number of exceptions. This *could* be very specific JDBC PostgreSQL driver error. That is why I'm wondering about this design in general: is it something legal or illegal to do so?

Comment: Look at this  http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/performance_optimizing_spring_hibernate_transactions/

Comment: Nothing about rollback and throwing runtime exceptions there

Comment: @Andremoniy thx for accepting, to be honest I don't remember writing this and now after reading it, I don't remember anything ))) might need to refresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as far as I understand, you are worried about the roll-back. In this case a `readOnly` is a `select statement` and usually there is nothing to roll-back from a `read`. The only place where this is handy is when you read under a lock and when the transaction finishes you release that lock.

AFAIK `readOnly` will set the flushmode to `FlushMode.NEVER` and that is good and bad at the same time. Good, because there will no dirty checking, as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/readonly.html). Bad because if you call a **read/write**  transaction within a `readOnly` transaction, the transaction will silently fail to commit because the session is not flushed. This is easily testable btw - and I hope things have not changed since I've tried this.

Then there is the pool of connections. I know that `C3P0`'s default policy is to rollback any uncommitted work. The flag to control this is `autoCommitOnClose`.

Then there is [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332706/does-postgresql-run-some-performance-optimizations-for-read-only-transactions) about `readOnly` and `postgres` - which I have not worked with and can't really tell my opinion on.

Now to your point about `Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only`. For a `readOnly` transaction there might be nothing to roll-back as I said before, so this *really* depends on how you chain your `@Transactional` methods IMO.